# Implement filtering in RetrievalQA chain

Tags: python, azure, langchain, large-language-model, azure-openai

I have been working on implementing the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/using-pgvector-llms-and-langchain-with-google-cloud-databases/) using RetrievalQA from Langchain with LLM from Azure OpenAI API.
I've made progress with my implementation, and below is the code snippet I've been working on:

```
import os
# env variables
os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"] = "azure"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "<YOUR_API_VERSION>"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "<YOUR_API_KEY>"
os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"] = "https://<SPACE_NAME>.openai.azure.com/"

# libary imports 
import pandas as pd

from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains.router.llm_router import LLMRouterChain,RouterOutputParser
from langchain.embeddings import GPT4AllEmbeddings
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI
from langchain.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.chains.qa_with_sources.retrieval import RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain
from langchain.document_loaders import DataFrameLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import (RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter, 
                                            CharacterTextSplitter)
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.vectorstores import utils as chromautils
from langchain.embeddings import (HuggingFaceEmbeddings, OpenAIEmbeddings, 
                                  SentenceTransformerEmbeddings)
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback
# 

# toy = 'Search in the documents and find a toy that teaches about color to kids'
toy = 'Search in the documents and find a toy with cards that has monsters'


all_docs = pd.read_csv(data) # data is the dataset from the tutorial (see above)

print('Model init \u2713')

print('---->  Azure OpenAI \u2713') 
llm_open = AzureChatOpenAI(
                           model="GPT3",
                           max_tokens = 100
                          )
print('Create docs \u2713')

loader = DataFrameLoader(all_docs, 
                         page_content_column='description' # column description in data
                        )
my_docs = loader.load()
print'Create splits \u2713')
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=512, 
                                      chunk_overlap=0
                                      )
all_splits = text_splitter.split_documents(my_docs)
print('Init embeddings \u2713')

chroma_docs = chromautils.filter_complex_metadata(all_splits)
# embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
my_model_name = "sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2"
embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name=my_model_name)

print('Create Chromadb \u2713')
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(all_splits, 
                                    embeddings,
                                   # metadatas=[{"source": f"{i}-pl"} for i in \
                                             # range(len(all_splits))]
                                   )
print('Create QA chain \u2713')
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
                                       llm=llm_open,
                                       chain_type="stuff",
                                        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 10}),
                                       verbose=True,)

print('*** YOUR ANSWER: ***')

with get_openai_callback() as cb:
            llm_res = qa_chain.run(toy)
            plpy.notice(f'{llm_res}')
            plpy.notice(f'Total Tokens: {cb.total_tokens}')
            plpy.notice(f'Prompt Tokens: {cb.prompt_tokens}')
            plpy.notice(f'Completion Tokens: {cb.completion_tokens}')
            plpy.notice(f'Total Cost (USD): ${cb.total_cost}')**strong text**
```

In the tutorial, there's a section that filters products based on minimum and maximum prices using a SQL query. However, I'm unsure how to achieve similar functionality using RetrievalQA in Langchain while also retrieving the sources.
The specific section in the tutorial that I'm referring to is:

```
results = await conn.fetch("""
         WITH vector_matches AS (
                 SELECT product_id, 
                        1 - (embedding <=> $1) AS similarity
                 FROM product_embeddings
                 WHERE 1 - (embedding <=> $1) > $2
                 ORDER BY similarity DESC
                 LIMIT $3
         )
         SELECT product_name, 
                list_price, 
                description 
         FROM products
         WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM vector_matches)
               AND list_price >= $4 AND list_price <= $5
         """, 
         qe, similarity_threshold, num_matches, min_price, max_price)
```

How to implement this filtering functionality using the RetrievalQA chain in Langchain and also retrieve the sources associated with the filtered products?